# Contract migration from Ethereum to L2

Tags: compiler, vyper, migration, layer-2

I am trying to figure out is it posible and how to migrate contracts from Ethereum main net to other L2. 
So here what I found:

1. Migrating from contract in Solidity from Ethereum to Optimism is pretty much simple whit exclusion of some small incompatiblies between EVM and OVM.
2. Migrating from contract in Solidity/Vyper from Ethereum to Polygon is straight forward due to EVM compatibility
3. Migrating from contract in Solidity/Vyper from Ethereum to Arbitrum is straight forward due to EVM compatibility

What about contract in Vyper from Ethereum to Optimism? Is it possible?

**Edit: In p.2 I was wrongly mentioned Optimism again**

Comment: You mentiones Optimism twice, perhaps you were trying to mention another one, polygon maybe?

Comment: You are absolutely right

Comment: https://medium.com/ethereum-optimism/the-future-of-optimistic-ethereum-7f22d987331
They talk about how vyper will have support.